# React-native yarn android @homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation Execution failed for task ':homee_react-native-mapbox-navigation:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-navigation

I have installed node package @homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation for quick turn-by-turn navigation in my react-native android app, but when I run `yarn android`, got below error:

```
> Configure project :homee_react-native-mapbox-navigation
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Task :homee_react-native-mapbox-navigation:compileDebugKotlin

> Task :homee_react-native-mapbox-navigation:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
72 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 70 up-to-date
e: /home/cipto/Code/mapbox/mapboxnav/node_modules/@homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation/android/src/main/java/com/homee/mapboxnavigation/MapboxNavigationManager.kt: (11, 19): Unresolved reference: maps
```

.
.
.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':homee_react-native-mapbox-navigation:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
```

have been following the gude in readme at https://github.com/homeeondemand/react-native-mapbox-navigation, by the way I installed the package which come from the github (latest version 2.00 master branch) by running this:

`yarn add homeeondemand/react-native-mapbox-navigation#master`

Answer (score 0):

I have also try that package and got the same error, after I upgrade the kotlin version into 1.6.0, the error went away.
[image: build.gradle kotlin version]